# How to find a merge the specific data with the name?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the name of specific gene in my data. That's what I did so far:

```
gnames = unique(data_rd[,1])
gnames= gnames[2:length(gnames)]
```

gnames contain all of the genes to which I have to find the name.

```
gdata = lapply(list_of_data,function(x) x[3:nrow(x),1,9])
```

gdata is a set of genes with their names but in different files and some of them might be repeated in few files.

That's how I created list_of_data:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list_of_data = lapply(tbl, read.csv)
```

So let's explain it on an example:

```
gnames:

Gene1
Gene2
Gene3
Gene4
Gene5
Gene6
Gene7

gdata:

Gene1 NameOfGene1
Gene5 NameOfGene5
Gene7 NameofGene7

Gene2 NameOfGene2
Gene6 NameOfGene6

Gene3 NameOfGene3
Gene4 NameOfGene4
```

I want R to find the name of all of genes from gnames by looking into this list_of_data.

```
> head(gnames)
[1] "ZZ_FGCZCont0025" "ZZ_FGCZCont0099" "ZZ_FGCZCont0126" "ZZ_FGCZCont0146"
[5] "AT1G19570"       "ZZ_FGCZCont0158"


> head(gdata) ## edited, too big.
[[1]]
                  X
3   ZZ_FGCZCont0025
4   ZZ_FGCZCont0099
5   ZZ_FGCZCont0126
6   ZZ_FGCZCont0146
7       AT1G19570.1
8   ZZ_FGCZCont0158
9       AT5G38480.1
10  ZZ_FGCZCont0050
X.8
3                                                                                                                                                                                     gi|1346343|sp|P04264| K2C1_HUMAN KERATIN, TYPE II CYTOSKELETAL 1 (CYTO 
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             sp|K1C9_HUMAN| 
5                                                                                                                                                                                     gi|71528|pir|| KRHU0 keratin 10, type I, cytoskeletal (clone lambda-KH 
6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             sp|K22E_HUMAN| 
7                                                                                                                                                     | Symbols: DHAR1, ATDHAR1, DHAR5 | dehydroascorbate reductase | chr1:6773462-6774413 REVERSE LENGTH=213
8                                                                                                                                                                                     gi|88041|pir||A31994 keratin 10, type I, epidermal - human gi|623409 ( 
9                                                                                                                                                             | Symbols: GRF3, RCI1 | general regulatory factor 3 | chr5:15410277-15411285 FORWARD LENGTH=255
10                                                                                                                                                                                    gi|71536|pir|| KRHU2 keratin, 67K type II cytoskeletal - human (fragme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
lapply(gdata, function(x)x[x[,1] %in% gnames, 2])
```

I tested with the following data:

```
set.seed(123)
gnames <- sample(LETTERS, 10)
num.rows <- sample(10:12)
gdata <- lapply(num.rows, function(i)data.frame(X    = sample(LETTERS, i),
                                                Name = sample(LETTERS, i)))
```

Note that your code could greatly benefit from `gdata` being stored in a better manner. From your sample data, it seems the colnames are `X` and `X.8`: you should use more meaningful names and use them in your code rather than having to make assumptions on what column index contains what data (You forced me to use `1` instead of `"Gene"` and `2` instead of `"GeneName"`.) You could also imagine making `gnames` a data.frame with a `Gene` column so you can rely on `merge` to do the work you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and some tips how I should treat my data! Very helpful!